# Sort music based on genre

Tags: windows, music

Is there any Windows software that would recognise the genre of music files and sort them accordingly even if there are no user made tags.

Comment: MusicBrainz might have something for you, if you have MP3 songs without ID3 tags. http://musicbrainz.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SongKong](http://www.jthink.net/songkong) is can automatically match songs to releases in the Musicbrainz and Discogs databases update your songs with the genres and styles already assigned to releases in Discogs. You can also specify to ignore or change certain genres.

[image]

Disclaimer:I'm SongKong developer

Answer (score -1):

If you have your music properly tagged then I would recommend you use Media Monkey. (http://www.mediamonkey.com/). I have used them for years and they are fantastic and sync with most devices.

Comment: The requirement is *if there are no user made tags*.